# Is it serial voting to upvote every answer on a Q/A thread, even if each answer is by the same user?

Tags: discussion

Recently, some user went through the [Tips for golfing in Befunge 98](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16090/9498) and upvoted each post. Normally, this would be fine, it's not considered serial voting. However, all but one of the tips provided are by me. So I got 7 upvotes on answers. This apparently counted as serial upvoting, as the votes were reverted (well, most of them).

I get that one shouldn't upvote a single user, but this user seems to have upvoted each post in the Q/A thread, not just me. It just happens that most of the posts are posted by me, which is kind of unusual.

Today, I got 4 more upvotes spread across the answers. I wouldn't be surprised if they became serial upvotes again. Should these *really* be serial upvotes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I agree that this wasn't serial upvoting, but I don't think there's something that can be done about it.

When a user upvotes several answers of another user in rapid succession, the system automatically suspects foul play and invalidates the votes. That's usually a good thing, since everbody should vote based on the content of answers, not the user who posted them.

This is a corner case the system doesn't take into account, not least because you rarely would post seven answers to the same question on other SE sites.

Finally, while we can't reverse the vote reversal, rest assured that this incident will have no repercussions apart from the loss of deserved rep (in case you were worried about that).

Answer (score 0):

The exact details about what is and what isn't serial voting is a closely kept secret by the staff.

Having said that, you're probably fine, especially if those 4 answers weren't right after each other (answers of other people were upvoted in between). 4 is usually not enough to trigger the system anyway.

The serial upvoting reversal is something which happens in clear cases of targeted voting (among other reasons to prevent voting rings where 3 people keep upvoting each other into oblivion). That is, targeting a specific user. Targeting a specific question and upvoting all answers ([to 'napalm' a question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1512/52915)) is not something the system is intended against.

Source: I'm a Code Review regular with nearly 5k votes cast on that site alone. The rules for vote reversal don't differ between sites.